# Projects continuously fails to clean because of fail to delete file

Tags: android

I have browsed several topics surrounding this subject but none are quite recent and maybe someone else can help me. If I clean my project or even try to rebuild it a continuously get an error that says

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory 'K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build'
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0\com\example\seansandroid\myApp\Games
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0\com\example\seansandroid\myApp
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0\com\example\seansandroid
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0\com\example
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0\com
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms
    - K:\Android\DementiaApp\app\build\intermediates
```

The file in question is the intermediates. I have seen a lot of people say that you just need to delete this file. For some reason, even if I try to delete the intermediates, they just wont delete! Can anyone help me? This is really annoying.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried File > sync with file system ? it solves this problem with me

Comment: Hi Zain, this doesn't seem to do anything for my application

Comment: Hi @Sean O, you can try this out: From the right hand side: Gradle > MyProject > app > Tasks > build > clean

Comment: Again I get flagged with the same error. I will post the error. I've tried deleting this file from my app's directory, but the file just wont be deleted. Very frustrating

Comment: Do you have admin privileges to delete this directory? you may check its properties then

Comment: I am the Admin on my computer and i've even tried using PowerShell to remove the file, with no luck! I've just actually renamed the file to something else, allowing Android Studio to see it as 'missing' and regenerating another build file. The app works fine now!

Comment: glad it works, but still not scalable, you can check also the ownership of the file, you can be admin, but not the owner; just a guess

Comment: The file shows no properties for created, access etc. How would I see if i'm not the owner of the file? My user account is the only user on my desktop.

Comment: Rclick on the file  > properties > security tab > advanced > owner tab > Current owner field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199265/discussion-between-zain-and-sean-o).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post the solution to my own question because its worked for me and may help others in the future.

No matter what, my file would not allow me to delete it, regardless of administrative privileges.

By renaming the file, Android Studio identified the file as 'missing' and regenerated another build file. This then allowed me to rebuild and clean my project.

It now works again!