# Android Studio 'Clean Project' is not working

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

**What I have done:**

I have copied the same project('myProject') folder(which has no issues with clean/rebuild) to a new location keeping the previous folder as a backup and aiming to change the copied project to modify more. *Here the name of the project is the same only the location is different.

Then I opened my project in the new location and started to execute.

**Observations:**

No issues when I opened android studios initially and importing the project, and even the emulator is working. But when I tried to clean the project it says below error.

```
    Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build'
  Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
  - C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build\outputs\apk\debug
  - C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build\outputs\apk
  - C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build\outputs
```

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878246/projects-continuously-fails-to-clean-because-of-fail-to-delete-file) and tried with

> Gradle > MyProject > app > Tasks > build > clean –

But still I received the same output as mentioned below

```
> Task :app:clean FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
        >Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build'
          Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
          - C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build\outputs\apk\debug
          - C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build\outputs\apk
          - C:\Users\sach\Desktop\Project02\test2\backup20191126\myProject\app\build\outputs
```

Error is the same as when I try to rebuild without clean.

Emulator is also working here, but unable to clean and rebuild. 
It is the same project with same name but in different locations. I was wondering why this happens here. Because there were no issues before I copied this here. Any clue to get rid of this please.

Answer (score 2):

close project and delete the folder app\build\intermediates manually

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I tried this but when I close the project, only 'output' folder is available in the mentioned directory, no intermediates folder

Comment: then delete the build folder ,your project will rebuild again .

Comment: While this works, I have to do it manually every time I want to clean the project.

Comment: There is no build folder? Note: This project was imported from eclipse.